# Help driving a display

Tags: driver, display, drive

I am trying to figure out a way to drive this LCD display, the datasheet can be found here https://datasheetspdf.com/mobile/611974/LG/LB070WV1/1 on page 8 it has some info on the connector/interface type.

A couple of key things I picked out was that it is a 40-pin ribbon cable in a CN1 config and that the connector model is FH12K-40S-0.5SH which brings up this with a quick Google https://m.panelook.com/connector_modeldetail.php?id=1139

I know the driver I need has to have a 40pin connector on it to be able to connect to the LCD but I know that doesn't mean by default it will drive it, what other info do I need to figure out here before going and searching for a driver, things like CN1, TTL and LVDS have popped up but I'm a little lost.

Came across this as a possible solution
https://thepihut.com/products/adafruit-tfp401-hdmi-dvi-decoder-to-40-pin-ttl-breakout-with-touch

Hoping someone can help, thanks!

Comment: Unless you have a 540V 3.5W inverter for the lamp and VGA or HDMI , what can you use?

Answer (score 0):

I'll not search and find a driver for you, but at least it's worth to provide some info for you to find/get one.

First, the LCD panel is a 480x800 24-bit RGB LCD panel. So the driver has to have **24-bit RGB output interface**. There are ones having both LVDS and RGB output support (LVDS and RGB are different signalling protocols), so make sure that the driver must have RGB interface.

Second, the backlight is a tough requirement. Without backlight the LCD panel is nothing. Your LCD panel has CFL inside so you need a CFL backlight driver which is not common these days. There are some combo drivers (i.e. LCD driver with backlight driver) but you may need a separate CFL backlight driver.

Third, connectors. Today 40-pin LCD connectors and pinouts are mostly common for different brands/resolutions, and there are lots of adapter cables but you still need to be careful because there are lots of LVDS adapter cables which don't match your requirements. Some drivers also provide adapter cables as well. Make sure you find adapter cables for RGB, not LVDS.

NOTE: Please don't ask questions like "I found this, can this be used?" because they will be considered as off-topic.

Comment: Thanks, I've came to the conclusion to find a 7inch lcd that fits, and works with a Raspberry pi put the box or a compatable driver board.